# Can't get a domain verified on AWS after transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

After transferring a domain from another registrar to AWS, I can't get it verified in the Certificate Manager. I created a hosted zone, the `CNAME` records created by the Certificate Manager are there, I tried with the DNS tester - the records seem good. However it still says "pending validation". I tried a few times, waited a couple of days and it doesn't seem it will work.

I'm totally out of ideas, any help?

Answer (score 0):

DNS validation require 2 things to be setup correctly. **Record Name** and **Record Value**
Check if you're correctly setting these in Route53. Reference Doc here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html

Now 2 issues which are very common

1. In the Record Name part confirm that you're not adding your domain name in the value. `_X` is the only part you have to copy-paste. If you copy _X.YourDomain then 'YourDomain' part is duplicated
2. Record Value ends with `.` (a period / dot). Don't remove that period

You can verify the settings from https://mxtoolbox.com/ it has various configurations like A record, CNAME, DNS Validation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was that I had nameservers pointing to DigitalOcean, instead of my hosted zone on Route 53. Silly, I know.